# リストから複数のValueを持つDictへの変換方法

Tags: python, python3

リストからDict型へ変換するコードを作成しているのですが，うまくいきません．
リストのデータとして`[1061, 1578, 877, 1010, 1182, 877, 1182]`のような7つの値が入った状態から，最初の値(この例では`1061`)をKey，残る6つの値をValueとしてDict型に変換したいです．
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これで出来るでしょう。

```
originallist = [1061, 1578, 877, 1010, 1182, 877, 1182]

targetdict = {originallist[0]:originallist[1:]}
```